# multi level model and intraclass correlation coefficient

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, intraclass-correlation

Let's say I have a data set with 4 variables: x1, x2, x3 and y. I have multiple measurements for every value of x1 and I want to perform linear regression. The goal of my research is to show proof that the coefficients on x2, x3, x4 and the intercept are significantly different from one another.

From what I understand, I need to run a mixed effects regression with random slopes and random intercepts (correct me if I'm wrong), and I could calculate ICC for every coefficient to get a measure of how different or how similar the coefficients are.

I used statsmodels.formula.api mixedlm in Python.

```
model = statsmodels.formula.api.mixedlm("y ~ x2 + x3", data, groups= "x1",
                     vc_formula = {"x2" : "0 + x2", "x3": "0 + x3"}).fit()
```

I get the following results:

```
           Mixed Linear Model Regression Results
===========================================================
Model:             MixedLM  Dependent Variable:  review    
No. Observations:  4761     Method:              REML      
No. Groups:        31       Scale:               0.9916    
Min. group size:   2        Log-Likelihood:      -6818.7489
Max. group size:   608      Converged:           Yes        
Mean group size:   153.6                                   
-----------------------------------------------------------
                 Coef.  Std.Err.   z    P>|z| [0.025 0.975]
-----------------------------------------------------------
Intercept         3.416    0.126 27.119 0.000  3.169  3.663
x1                0.036    0.049  0.722 0.470 -0.061  0.132
x2               -0.004    0.051 -0.069 0.945 -0.103  0.096
x1 Var            0.021    0.005                                
x2 Var            0.043    0.016                           
===========================================================
```

and I plan on calculating ICCs diving the variance by the scale.
$$
ICC_1 = 0.021 \div 0.9916
$$

and

$$
ICC_2 = 0.043 \div 0.9916
$$

Is this approach correct for what I'm trying to do? I understand the intra class coefficients are not proof the coefficients are significantly different from one another, but they are a first step at showing how different or similar they are.

I'm not sure how to perform hypothesis testing to show the coefficients are different, any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

The ICC is a measure of the proportion of variance in the dependent variable that is due to factors at the cluster (as opposed to observation) level. It's something you calculate for the model as a whole, not for individual variables. So let's say you have a dataset where you have multiple observations nested within subjects. if you ran a model without any predictor variables, but a random subject-level intercept then an ICC of .45 would tell you that 45% of the total variance in the DV is due to  subject level factors (things that don't change over time), and the remaining 55% is due to stuff that does change over time. If you added some predictor variables to the model, the ICC now tells you the proportion of the *unexplained* variance (after accounting for the predictors) that is at the subject level. However the interpretation of the ICC I just gave only works if you don't include random slopes in the model. Once you do the interpretation gets more complicated.

But you can see that nothing here tells you anything about how different one coefficient is from another. If in any model - multilevel or otherwise - you want to know if one coefficient is significant different from another, then just do a post hoc Wald test. You don't need to allow the slopes to vary randomly to do this, you're just asking if one coefficient is significantly different from the other.